# SELECT with OR using two columns with index is very slow

Tags: sql, performance, composite-primary-key, database-indexes, cockroachdb

There is a table with the following definition in my Cockroach database:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_value (
    foo_id_a INT NOT NULL,
    foo_id_b INT NOT NULL,
    value FLOAT NULL,
    create_date_time TIMESTAMP NULL,
    update_date_time TIMESTAMP NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "primary" PRIMARY KEY (foo_id_a ASC, foo_id_b ASC),
    INDEX foo_value_foo_id_a_foo_id_b_idx (foo_id_a ASC, foo_id_b ASC),
    INDEX foo_id_a_idx (foo_id_a ASC),
    INDEX foo_id_b_idx (foo_id_b ASC),
    FAMILY "primary" (foo_id_a, foo_id_b, value, create_date_time, update_date_time)
)
```

It contains roughly 400000 rows.

Querying for one of the two IDs is fast:

```
SELECT * FROM foo_db.foo_value WHERE foo_id_a = 123456;
takes 0.071 s

SELECT * FROM foo_db.foo_value WHERE foo_id_b = 123456;
takes 0.086 s
```

However querying for one `OR` the other is very slow:

```
SELECT * FROM foo_db.foo_value WHERE foo_id_a = 123456 OR foo_id_b = 123456;
takes 2.739 s
```

Why is this?

The results from `EXPLAIN` look as follows:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM foo_db.foo_value WHERE foo_id_a = 321210483;
+-------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Level | Type | Field |      Description      |
+-------+------+-------+-----------------------+
|     0 | scan |       |                       |
|     0 |      | table | foo_value@primary     |
|     0 |      | spans | /321210483-/321210484 |
+-------+------+-------+-----------------------+


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM foo_db.foo_value WHERE foo_id_b = 321210483;
+-------+------------+-------+------------------------+
| Level |    Type    | Field |      Description       |
+-------+------------+-------+------------------------+
|     0 | index-join |       |                        |
|     1 | scan       |       |                        |
|     1 |            | table | foo_value@foo_id_b_idx |
|     1 |            | spans | /321210483-/321210484  |
|     1 | scan       |       |                        |
|     1 |            | table | foo_value@primary      |
+-------+------------+-------+------------------------+


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM foo_db.foo_value WHERE foo_id_a = 321210483 OR foo_id_b = 321210483;
+-------+------+-------+-------------------+
| Level | Type | Field |    Description    |
+-------+------+-------+-------------------+
|     0 | scan |       |                   |
|     0 |      | table | foo_value@primary |
|     0 |      | spans | ALL               |
+-------+------+-------+-------------------+
```

Comment: What does the proposed and actual execution plans look like?

Comment: @SimonPrice: Do you mean the output of `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are asking for is an index optimization that uses *two* different indexes in the `or`.  Alas, SQL engines do not in general support this optimization (although Oracle does as might some other databases).

You are best off using `union all`:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo_db.foo_value
WHERE foo_id_a = 123456;
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM foo_db.foo_value
WHERE foo_id_b = 123456 AND foo_id_a <> 123456;
```

(Note:  You might need to take `NULL` values into account for the second `WHERE` clause.)

Each of the subqueries will be correctly optimized using the index.

Comment: why "union all" is used and not just "union"? I don't think he wants to get duplicates.